# How to properly remove pointers of objects from a dynamic memory?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a method that when given a command, removed all pointers of objects stored in a vector. These pointers were all created on the heap using `new` command. This is what I have for the method and I am getting segmentation fault 11 error.

```
else if (command == "Clear") {
    size_t allGrades = grades.size();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < allGrades; ++i) {
        grades[0] = nullptr;
        delete grades[0];
    }
}
```

where `grades` is the vector of pointers that have been allocated on the heap. How would I fix this?

Comment: Well your code should read `delete grades[i]; grades[i] = nullptr;` but that's not causing your crash. The bug is somewhere in the rest of your code. You should really post a complete program, beginners often think the bug is somewhere else than it really is

Comment: @Simon: We'll need some more code to see what's going on. For the time being, try using`std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers where you have ownership

Comment: Learn to use [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container), and provide some [MCVE] in your next question

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve].  As shown, your code cannot crash, although it will cause the original value of `grades[0]` (if not null) to be leaked.   Most likely, other code in your program is causing the problem.  Generally speaking, undefined behaviour OFTEN manifests as symptoms in code completely unrelated to the actual cause of the problem  (despite people insisting "no, the crash was here, so the cause is here")

Answer (score 2):

```
    grades[0] = nullptr;
    delete grades[0];
```

must be

```
    delete grades[i];
    grades[i] = nullptr;
```

else you do not delete the element saved in `grades` (set 0 before to delete, and you always look at the first element in grades) so you create memory leaks

{edit add}
"These pointers were all created on the heap using new command" : using *new* the allocated memory cannot be into the stack

Comment: Yes but the code posted is basically a no-op, so the OPs crash is somewhere else

Comment: Yes but to say all of that into a remark is not very practical.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to fix this is not to have owning raw pointers. Most likely* you don't need to `new` your grade objects and then store pointers in the vector.

Change `std::vector<Grade *>` to `std::vector<Grade>`, and your snippet becomes

```
else if (command == "Clear") {
    grades.clear();
}
```

*If you really need to dynamically allocate your `Grade` objects, you should use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Grade>>`, and construct them with `std::make_unique` not `new`. The clearing is unchanged from the value case.